# Infinite recursion in templates

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, template-meta-programming

Suppose I have a proxy class called `List` which is nothing more than a holder for a bunch of `typename`s:

```
template<typename... items> class List { 
  constexpr size_t SizeOf = /*Magic code that determines the length*/;
};
```

And suppose I have another class which is supposed to take to `Lists` and output a version where the smaller one is padded with `null_t`s:

```
template<class flist,class slist>
class Pad{
  typedef /*Undertermined*/ Flist;
  typedef /*Undertermined*/ Slist;
};
```

The only real problem is breaking the recursion....normally in template recursion you just specialize and then you can end it.

Here is a little different because there is no way (at least that I can see) to tell by the template deceleration the difference between the two list.

I tried to use a `std::conditional` to end the cycle but that does not work.

Here is an example:

```
template<int x>
class Mine{
  typedef std::conditional<x == 12, Mine<x>::value, Mine<x+1>::value> value;
};
```

Even though I have the `x==12` condition it still needs (or wants) to flush out the `Mine<x+1>::value`.

So what is the general strategy for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a non-recursive solution for the implementation of `Pad`, but it also shows how you can use partial specialization to avoid instantiating templates based on a condition:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<class... Ts> struct List { static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts); };
struct null_t { };

template<std::size_t> using make_null_t = null_t;

template<class, class> struct pad_imp2;
template<class... Ts, std::size_t... Is> struct pad_imp2<List<Ts...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
   using type = List<Ts..., make_null_t<Is>...>;
};

// Don't instantiate make_index_sequence if L::size >= S.
template<class, std::size_t, bool> struct pad_imp { using type = void; };
template<class L, std::size_t S> struct pad_imp<L, S, true>
{
   using type = typename pad_imp2<L, std::make_index_sequence<S - L::size>>::type;
};

template<class L, std::size_t S> using pad_hlp = typename pad_imp<L, S, L::size < S>::type;

template<class L1, class L2> struct Pad
{
   using L1_padded = std::conditional_t<L1::size < L2::size, pad_hlp<L1, L2::size>, L1>;
   using L2_padded = std::conditional_t<L2::size < L1::size, pad_hlp<L2, L1::size>, L2>;
};

int main()
{
   using list1 = List<short, int, long>;
   using list2 = List<double>;
   std::cout << std::is_same<Pad<list1, list2>::L1_padded, list1>::value << '\n';
   std::cout << std::is_same<Pad<list1, list2>::L2_padded, List<double, null_t, null_t>>::value << '\n';
}
```

The padding is done by generating a list of `null_t`s using the dummy `make_null_t` alias template and a pack of indices of the right size.

Answer (score 1):

One way to stop the recursion in your second example is to use boost.mpl. For example,

```
#include <boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/bool.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/integral_c.hpp>

template<int x>
struct Mine {
  using type = typename boost::mpl::eval_if<boost::mpl::bool_<x == 12>,
                                   boost::mpl::integral_c<short, 12>,
                                   Mine<x+1>
                                  >::type;
};
```

In the above example, it will always give you 12 as a value, regardless of the argument (as long as it is less or equal to 12).

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need to break recursion at Mine structure. If that is right, you can use full template specialization of this struct (for implementing terminal case of recursion). It looks like that:

```
template<>
struct Mine<123456>{
  // It is struct represents end of recursion
};
```

It is simple example of usage this approach for computing factorial:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
struct Factorial
{
   static const int fact = N * Factorial<N - 1>::fact;
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0>
{
    static const int fact = 1;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Factorial<1>::fact << std::endl;
    std::cout << Factorial<3>::fact << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```